# Uploading test iPhone/iPod application from iTunes?

Tags: iphone, testing, upload

is there a way to upload application to registered development device from Windows PC with iTunes ? My boss want to see current beta version on one development iPod touch, but he uses Windows 7 and iTunes ... no OS X, no XCode. Is it possible ?

10x!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Ad Hoc provisioning profile (you can just use a Development profile).

I also recommend not using iTunes for shared devices, since it forces you to sync (thus losing apps not in that iTunes library). iPhone Configuration Utility lets you install apps without arbitrarily deleting them.

But if you have the time to set it up, iOS 4 supports "over-the-air" provisioning profile/app installation, described in [Distributing Enterprise Applications for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-DontLinkElementID_12); we have this running with some Python scripts in Linux — it automatically unzips builds, turns them into IPAs, and generates the manifest "files". Installing this way is *much* faster than downloading builds off the file server and unzipping them, let alone faffing with Xcode or iTunes.

You don't actually need an Enterprise account or distribution profile; you just need to generate the correct manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must can create an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile and a matching certificate.

You can add up to 100 devices on the iphone developer portal. To add an iPad/iPhone/iPod to the list, you must know its UDID.

Then you send the binary of the App and the Ad Hoc provisioning profile to the user (your boss). He will drag both files (the binary is actually a folder) to iTunes and when he syncs his device - he will get the application.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode let you "Build and Archive" your application to distribute to another people.

In Xcode, in the Build Menu, click Build and Archive to do so (make sure that you are in Device configuration).

[image: Xcode screenshot]

When your application is build, Xcode will open the organizer windows, just go in "Archived Applications" tab to see your last build.

[image: Organize windows]

On the bottom you will see 3 buttons. In order to distribute the app to your boss, you should click on "Share Application".

XCode will propose you to sign application with a valid developer profile. You should create one for your boss (with his iPhone UDID like Tal Bereznitskey said).

[image: Organizer windows 2]

Now you can choose to saved the ipa file on  your disk or send it directly by email. Don't forget to join the provisioning file too.

Your boss as just to drag the provisioning profile into iTunes first, then the ipa file and synchronize to get the app on his phone.

Hope this helps !